# How do I install extra python packages on Datalab if they are not supported by pip?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, matplotlib-basemap, google-cloud-datalab

I tried to install basemap within Datalab using pip:

```
%bash
pip install basemap
```

and got the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking basemap
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement basemap
Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for basemap
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How do I install extra packages on Datalab if they are not supported by pip?

Answer (score 4):

Use apt-get install.  In a cell of your notebook:

```
%bash
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

Then, remember to restart your kernel (by Reset Session)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for this:

```
%%bash
pip install package_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to first do

apt-get update

So it gets the updated list of packages.

Answer (score 1):

Basemap doesn't come with the google datalab out of the box.

Note: I use shorthand '!' to indicate a bash command, rather than '%bash' as the google documents usually do.

As of Feb 2019, this works on a fresh google datalab:

**Step 1: Install Pre-requisites**

- `!apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated build-essential libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos++-dev`
- `!pip install pyproj pyshp`

**Step 2: Install the whole package**

- `!pip install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz`

**Step 3: Check the package has been installed correctly**

- `!pip freeze`

**Step 4: Import the module**

- `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

@Lak: You will need to update page 155 of your book - Data Science on the Google Cloud platform as the instructions there won't work; basemap is one of the more difficult packages to get working.

Answer (score 0):

The command suggested by Lak might have worked in the past but it's no longer the case: as of today (Aug 2017) Google Datalab instances reject the command listed here

```
%bash

echo 'Y' | apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

outputs the error message:

E: Unable to locate package python-mpltoolkits.basemap 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-mpltoolkits.basemap'

Execution from the shell (vs. notebook) outputs the same error.

After searching various sources I found a fix that worked for me: from the notebook in Datalab I added an update cmd before the actual install, like this:

```
%bash 

echo 'Y' | apt-get update

echo 'Y' | apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
```