# Add Caffe to Datalab Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, caffe, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to run a Jupyter notebook that uses Caffe. Caffe  is not included in datalab. I am trying to install that library from within the Jupyter notebook (as recommended in the datalab docs), but am running into problems.

I am new to datalab, and a novice with such things generally. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

The datalab documentation suggests
[3 strategies](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) 
for adding a python library that is not [already included](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/key-concepts#included_libraries). I am concentrating on the first two of these strategies.

The platform for my datacloud instance is:

*platform.platform()*
'Linux-4.4.111+-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid'

Below I'll list various things I've tried and the error messages I got.
For the first strategy, I tried these things in a cell of the same notebook.

(Attempt 1)

```
!pip install caffe
#results in the error:
#Collecting caffe
#  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement caffe (from 
#versions: )
#No matching distribution found for caffe

!pip install caffe-cpu
#results in the same error as above
```

I realized from my research that caffe could not be installed with pip, so I tried:

(Attempt 2)

```
!apt-get install caffe
#results in the error:
#Reading package lists... Done
#Building dependency tree       
#Reading state information... Done
#E: Unable to locate package caffe

!apt-get install caffe-cpu
#results in the same error as above
```

Based on another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047155/how-do-i-install-extra-python-packages-on-datalab-if-they-are-not-supported-by-p), I tried the following for both caffe and caffe-cpu:

(Attempt 3)

```
%bash
echo 'Y' | apt-get update
echo 'Y' | apt-get install caffe-cpu
#This results in output with a lot of warnings, but ends with the error:
#E: Unable to locate package caffe-cpu
#Stack Overflow prevented me from posting the entire thing, thinking it was spam
```

(Attempt 4)

Based on the [second strategy](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) recommended in the documentation, I tried running this code in a separate notebook:

```
%%bash
echo "pip install caffe" >> /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
cat /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
#This resulted in the error:
#bash: /usr/local/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by bash)
```

I got the same results when I ran:

```
%%bash
echo "apt-get install caffe" >> /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
cat /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on my end to install caffe-cpu, and it seems that the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` doesn't have the needed repositories to install it, in the datalab instance. To workaround this issue, I used the following commands, in a created notebook:

```
!echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main\n\
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main\n\
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main\n\
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main\n\
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main\n\
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will add the necessary `debian/stretch` repositories that include the caffe-cpu package.

Note: Strangely I didn't need to add the `-e` flag to the `echo` command in order to correctly read the newlines, you can check if the file has been correctly updated by doing `!cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Once that is done, run the following command:

```
!apt-get update && apt-get install caffe-cpu -y --allow-unauthenticated
```

Once the command finishes, the caffe-cpu package will be installed in your VM.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joan. The debian stretch and security files do seem to be successfully appending to the sources.list file. However (and I tested this on a fresh instance, in both Python 2 and 3 notebooks), I seem to have the same problem.  I try to import caffe using... caffe = __import__("caffe-cpu") ...in order to account for the hyphen, but still get the error "No module named 'caffe-cpu'".

Comment: I think the issue is that the location of the `caffe` module is not in the python path. Try to add this line before importing it: `sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')`. In my end, running `!python3 -c "import sys;sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages');import caffe"` did import the module.

Comment: That does get the import started, but I then get an error as it loads:

Comment: ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf   In reading about this error, it seems like it would be a bit complicated to solve this issue. I hate to say it Joan, but I am starting to think of alternate approaches to this project that do not involve Caffe at all, so please don't spend too much energy :). However, if it's clear to you what's happening here, i would gladly try any suggestions you have. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This is the only thing I have found that could help, [this documentation](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started) uses a custom Docker image to build the datalab instance. I haven't been able to test it on my side, but it can work. The idea is to modify the `Dockerfile.in` file and add the lines `RUN apt update` and `RUN apt install caffe-cpu -y`, and then run the rest of the commands as stated in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned before, there were [three strategies](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) listed in the docs. A custom docker file was the third. I was avoiding it because I am having all kinds of problems getting docker to run on my machine (and I still am). The documentation you posted is clear and helpful, and I do agree that this is probably gonna be the way to go. If I manage to get it running on my machine, I will post the results.